# Use curl and xpath to crawl website

Tags: php, curl, xpath

I want to crawl this site and get the table standing http://www.basketligaen.dk/da/top/turnering/stilling/, but when I try to get the content I get `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )` .
My code looks like this:

```
    $curl = curl_init('http://www.basketligaen.dk/da/top/turnering/stilling/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
    $elements = $xpath->query("//div[@id='3739']/table");
    print_r($elements);
```

I have crawled a lot of pages before, but I cant find the problem with this one - is there someone who can see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `table` element directly under the `div` element with `id="3739"`.

The table is under the `div` element with `id="3738"` and not directly, this should work:

```
//div[@id='3738']//table
```

Note the double-slash which means a parent-children relationship, but at any depth level.

---

As a side note, I don't particularly like the readability and the robustness of the current XPath expression - the `3738` id is kind of "cryptic", it does not bring any valuable data-oriented information and has a high chance to be changed. Probably, a better way would be to rely on the table header:

```
//div[. = 'Grundspil']/following-sibling::table
```

---

All that said, there is a bigger problem here - the table is a part of a JavaScript "widget" and is configured and loaded dynamically by your browser and it's JavaScript engine. When you download your page with "curl", you only get the very initial HTML page which does not contain the desired table.

One of the easiest (in terms of implementation) workarounds, would be to automate a real browser via, for example, [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). The points about the XPath expressions made above would still be applicable since, among others, there is also the "by xpath" locator.

Comment: When changing it to : $elements = $xpath->query("//div[@id='3739']//table"); and then printing the element : print_r($elements); - I still get : DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ). Shouldn't I get a length bigger than 0 or is it me who is missing something?

Comment: @AndreasBaran ah, do you get the empty result even if you use the other expression from the answer?

Comment: yes - when running this:$elements = $xpath->query("//div[. = 'Grundspil']/following-sibling::table");
    print_r($elements); I still get an empty result

Comment: @AndreasBaran ah, yeah, that's the other, bigger problem. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see the problem - but when  I echo $html;, I get the website and I also get the website with the league table, so I thougt that I had the elements to choose from, but maybe I am wrong :-(

Comment: @AndreasBaran hm, when I do that, I don't see the table and the "Grundspil" text in the response html..may be this is me doing something wrong..

Comment: Yeah that is odd - so when I run this :  $curl = curl_init('http://www.basketligaen.dk/da/top/turnering/stilling/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10');
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl); And then echo $html;
    die; I get the webpage with the league standing and the "Grundspil" text -  so that is very odd :-D

Comment: But thanks for your help - maybe I should just do it with a selenium server, thats maybe the quickest instead of doing all sort of quick fixes :-)

Comment: @AndreasBaran interesting - this is what I've got in the `$html` in the related block: `<div id="3738" class="mbtWidgetContainer"
data-widgetid="301" data-parameters='[{"arena_link_visible" : "1"...]'>
</div>` - no `table` element here..are you sure you are inspecting the `$html` variable?..