# How to get the value of div by classname from curl output

Tags: php, html, curl, dom, xpath

I have a php curl. It's working fine.

```
<?PHP

//here i have the post parameters/login   
 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
echo curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

?>
```

I get the output (as the webpage code). I want to get only one value, but i don't know, how to parse it with DOM/Xpath.

The output:

```html
<!-- Inner Container Start -->
            <div class="container">
               
                <!-- Panels Start -->
<div class="mws-form-message success" id="\&quot;updated\&quot;">
                Server started.
           </div><script id="facebook-jssdk" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">             
                $('#updated').hide().fadeIn(800).delay(6000).fadeOut(800)
            </script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="modules/teamspeak3/viewer/tsstatus.css">
 <div class="mws-panel grid_8">
                    <div class="mws-panel-header">
                    <span><i class="icon-graph"></i>server stat</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mws-panel-body">    
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.jquery.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.main.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.xmlhttp.js"></script>

                    <div class="mws-stat-container clearfix">
```

I only need the value of string: "Server started":

`<div class="mws-form-message success" id="\&quot;updated\&quot;">`

How can i get it ?

Comment: Having a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41514206/1305969) should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you want to use XPath to get the value:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($your_input_string);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$result = $xpath->query("//div[contains(@class,'mws-form-message')]");
echo trim($result[0]->nodeValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this snippet and it worked as expected

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->validateOnParse = true;
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body id="me">Test<br></body></html>');

var_dump($doc->getElementById('me')->nodeValue); // test
```

You can adapt it to your needs , also check the php docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php , it will let you figure out more solutions as well